# Connect SAP Retail using Java

Tags: java, sap-erp, jco

I am new to SAP Retail, got a task to connect and interact with the SAP Retail system using java in order to retrieve promotion, offer data.

I am looking for ways to do so, either using any Java API or Web services.

Please give me some ideas to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities.

- SAP functions can be easily turned into webservice, in which case you "just" have to call the  webservice as you do for any other one.
- Another possibility is to use the JavaConnector (JCO) provided by SAP. The current version is 3, and really differs from previous version. The connector is available at http://service.sap.com/connectors, but you need a marketplace account (something that the SAP people in your company/customer should be able to provide)

In both case, you will have to work with your SAP Expert(s) / Consultant(s) to get the info on what you have to call, or to develop specific code in the SAP system.

regards

Comment: You may also use some libraries built on top of SAP JCo, that provide an easier to use programming interface. One such a library is [sap4j](http://sap4j.com) which is useful if you need to retrieve, transform, and persist the data. It abstracts you from underlying SAP data structures, providing standard data structures. They provide some examples as well. Another well-known library is the [hibersap](http://hibersap.org/), which provides Hibernate like annotations to query data to an object model.

Answer (score 1):

The SAP system is complex to interface to. You need to use a file structure called [IDoc](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1376487).

You can get an idea of the scope of your problem [here](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Retail/IS-Retail).